# Apache + PHP-FPM + chroot results "File not found." error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php-fpm, chroot

I want to set chroot to the DocumentRoot using PHP-FPM pools' chroot attribute. With the settings below, whatever I do I get only a "File not found." error:

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/example.conf

```
[example]
user = example
group = example
listen = /var/run/php_fpm_example.sock
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chroot = /opt/jail/example/home/example
php_admin_value[open_basedir]=/opt/jail/example/home/example
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.domain.name
ServerAlias www.example.domain.name
DocumentRoot /opt/jail/example/home/example
<Directory /opt/jail/example/home/example>
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler php-script
</FilesMatch>
Action php-script /php5-fpm-handler
Alias /php5-fpm-handler /vhost_example
FastCGIExternalServer /vhost_example -socket /var/run/php_fpm_example.sock
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

So the website itself is located in /opt/jail/example/home/example. You may find it strange, but doesn't really matter, it is caused by jailkit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When do you get that error? When opening the DocumentRoot? Are there any files in the folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get that error when I open example.domain.name or www.example.domain.name.
I have an index.php in /opt/jail/example/home/example that contains a simple phpinfo(). However, when I place an index.html it will be opened successfully.

Comment: Did you check the source code, not that php isn't parsed correctly and just outputs your php source? what happens if you call www.example.domain.name/index.php?

Comment: The same happens. I instanned everything with apt-get, so they shall work fine.

Comment: What's the output of access and error log?

Comment: It does not show anything important.

Comment: You should at least see in which directory he's looking for the file ...

Comment: Ok, in /var/log/apache2 only two log files are modified when I try to reload the page:
1) error.log
http://pastebin.com/Kijv5Kgn

2) other_vhosts_access.log
http://pastebin.com/s2zNAQVp

Comment: The problem seems to be the first entry in your error.log. Check this question and answers for the same problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/418983/nginx-fastcgi-primary-script-unknown-when-configuring-userdir

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really understand that solution. Could you explain please?

Comment: Anyway, everything works fine if I remove the chroot setting from the example.conf pool. I guess it must be caused by a wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is running inside the chroot jail. So once you set this:

```
chroot = /opt/jail/example/home/example
```

Then the path `/opt/jail/example/home/example` becomes the path `/` for PHP. Because of that this is non-sensical:

```
php_admin_value[open_basedir]=/opt/jail/example/home/example
```

as PHP no longer has access to /opt/jail/example.... because it's outside of the root path.

You haven't posted it but you also need to make a change to the fastcgi_param config file, where you set the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter which probably looks like this:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

which needs to be changed to something like:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    webroot/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

where if you combine the values of `chroot` + `webroot` + `$fastcgi_script_name` you get the absolute path of the file on the disk. Because PHP is running in the chroot you don't need to include it in the path.

btw It's a better practice to have the chroot to be set to one level above the webroot, so that your application can write to log files that are within the chroot, but not in the webroot, so that there's no way for them to be accidentally downloaded by a user.

So your directories would be:

```
/opt/jail/example/home/          <-- chroot
/opt/jail/example/home/example   <-- Read only directory is exposed as webroot (or document root).
/opt/jail/example/home/var/log   <-- Writeable directory that holds log files.
```