# php-fm can not filnd path on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

Here is my pool setup for php-fpm:

```
[example.com]
; OUR CUSTOM SETTINGS
listen = 127.0.0.1:9002
prefix = /home/example
chroot = $prefix
; DEFAULT DEBIAN SETTINGS
chdir = /public_html
user = example
group = apache
listen.owner = example
listen.group = apache
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

and here is my apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example   
    ServerAlias example.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   $
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/example/public_html"
    ErrorLog "/home/example/logs"
    CustomLog "/home/example/logs1.log" combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/example/cgi-bin/
    Alias /phpmyadmin /home/phpmyadmin

#FastCgiExternalServer /home/example/public_html -host 127.0.0.1:9000
#AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
#Action php-fastcgi /etc/httpd/php/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi
#Alias /etc/httpd/php/sbin/php-fpm.fcgi /etc/httpd/php/sbin/php-fpm

 FastCGIExternalServer /home/example/public_html/php5.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9002

 <Directory /home/example/public_html>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
  Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5.fcgi
 </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/example/public_html">
      AllowOverride All  
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
    </Directory>

   <Directory "/home/phpmyadmin">
      AllowOverride All  
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm default.htm
      Options -Indexes
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I get error: `File not found.` I think problem is php-fpm can't find file....

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Who says you file not found? PHP or Apache?

Comment: It is probably php because when I open in browser non php file it  open without error...

Comment: I mean, you get it in your browser or it's a log file?

Comment: In browser...this error log get in apache: `[Wed Nov 18 00:49:29 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.68] FastCGI: server "/home/example/public_html/php5.fcgi" stderr: Primary script unknown` also when I use default apache config without virtual hosts all works fine and also when I use apache with virtual host and mod_php all works fine...

Comment: check your Fcgi setup ... This seems similar: http://serverfault.com/questions/418983/nginx-fastcgi-primary-script-unknown-when-configuring-userdir

Comment: how to find config file?

Comment: I suppose it's you who set up that ...

Comment: I set up but there is no fcgi setup file... I use Centos 6

Comment: When I compiled fastCGI it just added module to apache folder... didn't create any config file.